# After how many values is rand() likely to repeat a duplex pattern?

Tags: c, random, cryptography, statistics

RAND_MAX on my system is 32767.

I need to generate millions of passwords. I plan to do it as follows:

```
printf("%d%d",rand()+1,rand()+1);
```

Is this a good way to do it? After how many iterations is it likely that I would find a repetition?

Comment: Using `rand` for anything cryptography/security related is generally a bad idea.

Comment: And yeah, you might see a repetition on a second password right away. It's random, you know.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree with your first comment. I just used the Cyrptography tag to bring this question to the attention of Cryptographers on SO (since they are most likely to have an expert level knowledge of the randomness of rand).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I also agree with your second comment. However, I just want to know if it is likely enough? Or how likely is it? I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: If you're interested in how likely it is you can just run the numbers yourself. Generate millions of "passwords" and count the number of duplicates. That said, this doesn't look like a good way to generate passwords.

Comment: Can you calculate it assuming a perfect uniform distribution? Take the Birthday paradox in account and you will see that for 1M samples it will be pretty likely. Of course you should define what's acceptable for you.

Comment: @Kevin Good idea, thanks! Is there any other way that you would recommend more?

Comment: There is a 0.093% chance for NOT getting a duplicate if you create 1 million passwords like that (if rand() is uniform distributed): (1 - (1 - 1 / (32768 * 32768)) ^ 1000000) *100%

Comment: @user3121023 OT: That's kind of incorrect calculation in that comic, unfortunately... If we assume this technique is used, a simple dictionary attack will crack it in seconds. I think...

Comment: @user3121023 Um... well. Depends how many "common" words are these that will actually pop into ones brain.

Comment: @user Yeah, mathematically. What I mean that an average person will hardly have few thousand in their "common words" list. Still not bad, though.

Comment: @user3121023 I afraid it will only improve one brain which is above the average :P

Comment: "Since these are passwords, even a single repetition cannot be accepted.'  Why is that unacceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:

As exposed by @chux (see comment below), my original answer (based on the  "birthday attack") ignored possible duplicates relating to text concatenation and therefor was highly optimistic.

My original answer also ignores the flaws in the random generator used (`rand`), as indicated by Oliver Charlesworth).

Hence, my original answer of 39,320 iterations should be considered an overly optimistic best case scenario.

A closer (yet inaccurate) approximation would be 27,320 iterations.

**Original**:

According to the "birthday attack" calculation, each the combination of "random" numbers is likely to be repeated after 1.2 * sqr_root(32,767*32,767) = **39,320** iteration.

This means that you should find collisions by the time your code had generated 39,321 passwords.

However, since `rand` isn't cryptographically safe, your passwords aren't safe from the get-go (the seed could be compromised, causing the whole collection to become deterministic.

Comment: And if `RAND_MAX` happens also to correspond to the length of the random sequence, then there's **guaranteed** to be repeats after 16384 iterations ;)

Comment: Note OP is concatenating text.  `"123" "456"` will match `"12" "3456"`.  so many less than `32,768*32,768` combinations.

Comment: @chux thanks for pointing this out! I updated my answer, even though I ill prepared to calculate the effects of text concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use a secure random number generator. If you don't then somebody could simply request a few passwords, brute force the seed and then re-calculate each and every password generated before and after.

Pseudo random numbers have a very high cycle size. A cycle happens when a previous *state* of the random number generated is entered. After that the pseudo random number will just repeat itself indefinitely. The cycle size for secure random generators is however so stupendously huge that in practice they will never regenerate the same state and enter a cycle. The cycle size of `rand` depends on the implementation, but is likely relatively low - another reason why not to use it.

Of course, if you have a very short password with a small alphabet (the acceptable range of symbols) it is much more likely that a password itself will repeat. Finding a similar *pattern* in the random number generator is much more likely than having the RNG enter a previous state. For instance, retrieving a previously generated byte value will happen relatively quickly due to the birthday paradox.

How quickly you will find a duplicate is therefore linked to the specific password generator. For millions of passwords you would need to create a pretty strong password (the one you have shown is *not* a strong password). If you want to make sure that the password is unique you can store the password or a hash over the password in a huge table. Remember that storing a hash over the password has similar security as storing the password itself (!).

You are much better off removing the uniqueness requirement and linking the password with a user ID. If you want to have a unique PIN code then create a list of possible PIN codes of the right size and then perform a Fisher-Yates shuffle (again using a secure random number generator, of course).